# How to tell where a Service Reference was generated from?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service-reference

My Visual Studio 2010 project has a Service Reference defined. I can right click it to update the reference... but I have no idea what URL the reference was defined on, nor can I find a place to find this info to know how it is going to update.

Answer (score 2):

Within the `Service References\yourServiceName` folder, there is a file called `Reference.svcmap`. If you open this with a text editor, its an XML file and the following XML node should give you that information

```
<MetadataSources>
    <MetadataSource Address="http://something/something" 
                                 Protocol="http" SourceId="1" />
</MetadataSources>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you right-click the service reference, there should be a "Configure Service Reference" option. Selecting this will show you the URL.

Comment: That option doesn't exist for me. I am using VS2010 if that matters

Comment: @JarrodEverett: It should; take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Its in the Settings file under properties folder in your project.   Update service reference doesn't always work sometimes you just need to recreate the reference.

Comment: Well you can tell if you know what it is supposed to look like. I have used it mainly with my own services not other peoples.

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio follow these steps -

1. Right click `Service` and on context menu select `Configure Service Reference`
2. `Service Reference Popup` will show up.
3. `Client` > `Address` field will have URL to service reference.

[image]